# Using VowpalWabbit's hypersearch always output the same results

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I was trying to use VW's hypersearch script for hyperparameter optimization. However, I noticed that regardless of what parameters I was trying to optimize, results were always the same:
[vw-hypersearch results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exjfV.png)

Here are a few data points for better understanding:

```
shared |User interests= activities= custom_attrs= device=MOBILE city=Brasília |Session pageViews=0 tabViews=0 sessions=1
0:1.0:0.2 |Action variation=default 
|Action variation=var1 
|Action variation=var2 
|Action variation=var3 
|Action variation=var4 

shared |User interests= activities= custom_attrs= device=MOBILE city=São Paulo |Session pageViews=0 tabViews=0 sessions=2
|Action variation=default 
0:1.0:0.2412 |Action variation=var1 
|Action variation=var2 
|Action variation=var3 
|Action variation=var4 

shared |User interests= activities= custom_attrs= device=MOBILE city=Ouro Branco |Session pageViews=0 tabViews=0 sessions=1
|Action variation=default 
|Action variation=var1 
0:1.0:0.3023 |Action variation=var2 
|Action variation=var3 
|Action variation=var4
```

Does anyone know why would VW's output always be the same? What are some possible causes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing some options on your command line. At the very least you'll need to specify the -q option, in your case probably `-q::`

Could you add that to the vw options list and try again?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I've tried adding -q :: but results did not change (it was slower, though, as expected).

Still get the same values regardless of which HP I'm evaluating.

Answer (score 0):

Results all the same imply the predictions are all the same.  If you hand-run various hyperparameter choices, do you observe prediction stability?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, John!
First point: the examples I presented don't suggest otherwise? Already in the first three examples, we have different predictions (both value and action). It's worth mentioning that this data was captured using softmax explorer.
On the second point:
When using epsilon-greedy explorer, I see some stability. The pmf is always the same in this case, but the higher value changes its index in some cases depending on the input. When using a softmax explorer, now the pmf always changes, but the highest value less frequently. 
Let me know if you need more information.